# IntellIJ idea does not want to use my external library

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I have a school project to build a Jar library containing a basic card management system, then use it in the main project (a blackjack game)

With IDEA I separated the modules, then I built the jar artifact. I now have all my classes in my `jar`.

The generic card management module name is named `Carte` (card in french), generated into a `Carte.jar` file

Now I add this jar as a library for the `blakcjack` module...

I did an `import Carte.*;` which give me `unresolved symbol Carte` ...

Without import, I got unresolved symbol for classes from my library

How am i supposed to use my library?

[image]
[image]

Comment: add all code on the same jar instead importing the library =D

Comment: This is a requirmement from my school. My blackjack module has to import the card management system, built in a jar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the classes in your library are in the default package, i.e. they don't have a specified package name. `Carte` is the name of the module, but not a Java package. I marked what I mean on [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Swf.jpg).

Java doesn't allow importing classes from the default package, as per [Java language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5):

> It is a compile time error to import a type from the unnamed package.

So, you should avoid the default package to be able to use the classes from a library.

Another possible reason of why the classes seem to be in the default package is that you've improperly packed the jar.

Comment: Thanks ! My Module 'Carte' had indeed no package. Adding one and building the jar fixed the issue. Thanks !